# Magento 2.3.4 - infinite loop on checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I have upgraded from Magento CE 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 and on the checkout I get this error: [image: kout]

Has anyone had this problem before?

Theres nothing in the logs and I am on developer mode with debugging enabled.

Comment: Have you tried grepping the code for the error message? This may at least give you some useful clues, e.g. whether the error is generated within Magento or occurs in an interaction between the browser and an external API. A lot of payment methods are handled in the latter fashion, so their errors are never visible to Magento and can't be logged.

Comment: Having the same issue! Fresh 2.3.3 install, with 2.3.4 upgrade. app/design/frontend/module/vendor/requirejs-config.js Can't find this file - anyone else having an issue? Losing sales as I didn't think this would cause an issue.

Comment: Replace vendor/magento/module-checkout/model/Session.php with the 2.3.3 version - seemed to fix it for me

Answer (score 1):

Create custom class & copy required functionality of vendor/magento/module-checkout/model/Session.php class file of Magento 2.3.3 version in it.

Then, use that custom class in Magento 2.3.4 version where you have added dependency of Magento\Checkout\Model\Session class file.

Or you can use '\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart' class file to get all visible items of cart.

> **$this->cart->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Magento [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26786). It might be fixed in some Magento release

You could change the way you receive `Quote` in your module
See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314014) approach

```
$session = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$quote_repository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
$qid = $session->getQuoteId();
$quote = $quote_repository->get($qid);      
// retrieve quote items
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
```