# M 2.3.4 - "Infinite loop detected..." exception on OPC, how to get items in the cart?

Tags: checkout, exception, magento2.3.4, checkoutsession

I'm trying to get quote on checkout and this exception is thrown in

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\Session.php:241
```

exception.log

```
Message: Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path 
{"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-
6e4533bg2n381; Message: Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the 
looping path at /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi
/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): Infinite loop detected,
review the trace for the looping path at /public_html/vendor/magento
/module-checkout/Model/Session.php:241)"} []
```

The problem is in overridden `\Magento\Tax\Model\Config` `getShippingTaxClass()` where I use

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
$itemsCollection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
```

and this triggers the exception. There is no loop around it.

What would be to correct way of getting cart items in 2.3.4?

Comment: Found any fix for this?

Comment: @Olivier yes, I added my answer.

Comment: Any solution for the same I am facing the same issue after m2.3.3 upgrade 2.3.5 EE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting items directly from session was causing this error so I only got quote id from session and then used `CartRepositoryInterface` to retrieve items.

```
$session = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$quote_repository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
$qid = $session->getQuoteId();
$quote = $quote_repository->get($qid);      
// retrieve quote items
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
```

Comment: superb @Alan working for me... good job

Comment: It working thanks..